# Do I need to specify a data type boolean in typescript when the value is already set in false?

Tags: typescript

`public expanded: boolean = false;`

Can the above piece of code be simplified to something like `public expanded = false;`?

Just wondering if the transpiler will benefit from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes, you can simply write it as

```
public expanded = false;
```

This is because for primitive data types such as `boolean`, TypeScript will be able to automatically infer the type. In this case, expanded will definitely be typed as boolean without explicitly providing the boolean type.

For instance, if you try to reassign the `expanded` property somewhere along the code, with any other value that is not a boolean, such as a string,

```
this.expanded = '1';
```

you will realise that it will throw an error:

> TS2322: Type '"1"' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the typescript will infer the type automatically.